# Quartz job scheduler does not stop on Docker

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am creating a maven project to be installed as a plugin for Elasticsearch. This plugin has Quartz scheduler, and it actually works fine, until I want to stop it. It does not stop. On Windows, it does stop. I have implemented the job as InterruptableJob, and when I call 'interrupt(key)', it just returns false!! So, for sure the 'deleteJob(key)' won't work as well. Any ideas about that?

Here is the code for the InterruptableJob:

```
public class ReportJob implements InterruptableJob {


    private ReportService rs = new ReportService();
    boolean stopped = false;

    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        SchedulerContext schedulerContext = null;
        if(!stopped) {
            try {
                schedulerContext = context.getScheduler().getContext();
                rs.start(schedulerContext);
            } catch (SchedulerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {
        System.out.println("**************interrupting**************");
        stopped = true;
    }
}
```

and Here is what I am calling to interrupt and delete the job:

```
System.out.println("interrupt: " + scheduler.interrupt(new JobKey(jobName, JOB_GROUP)));
System.out.println("deleteJob: " + scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(jobName, JOB_GROUP)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your ReportService is something running on background threads?
It looks to me that the `if(!stopped)` is passed very quickly, and after that the job spends arbitrary time in `rs.start(schedulerContext);`. There is no new evaluation of stopping. Let's call this scenario 1.

I may be wrong and `rs.start()` starts background threads and terminates quite quickly as well. Let's call this scenario 2.

## For scenario 1:

Probably you want to call something like

```
rs.stop()
```

in your interrupt() method.

## For scenario 2:

You might need another job to bring down the ReportService again. The interrupt method will simply have no effect. Also be aware that the JVM terminates when the last thread has terminated - this usually does not work in Java AWT/Swing applications and it also will not work if ReportService has own threads running. In this case you need to actively bring down the ReportService's threads, or use `System.exit()` which is likely not what you want.